# Javascript: load data from a local csv dataset in a 2d array in one function and then be able to loop that array in another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, for-loop, multidimensional-array

My problem is related to javascript and csv file. The cvs file is from a excel and is located on the server side.
My final Goal is to to be able to do some statistics with these data...

I tried different methods using papaparse, csv-parser and I was getting some errors.

the following way seems to have some issue:

I used a asynch function getData() to convert it into a 2d array and it is working:

```js
async function getData(){
    const rep=await fetch('datan2.csv')
    const data=await rep.text();
    let fin=[]
    const table=data.split('\n').slice(1)
    table.forEach(row=>{
        const colums=row.split(',');
        tab=[colums[0], colums[1],colums[2]]
        fin.push(tab)  
        });
        return fin
    }
```

From the following code, I can easily loop the array **fin**

The problem now is when I try to get this array outside this function:

for example in the following code, where printing **t** is working but I cannot access a specific element of the array:

```js
t=getData()
    console.log(t)//working
    console.log(t[0][0])// not working here
```

Can someone help? because my final goal is to be able to loop the array out side the **getData** method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `forEach` with `For..of`. Like so

Replace

```
table.forEach(row=>{
   const colums=row.split(',');
   tab=[colums[0], colums[1],colums[2]]
   fin.push(tab)  
});
```

With

```
for(const row of table){
   const colums=row.split(',');
   tab=[colums[0], colums[1],colums[2]]
   fin.push(tab)
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer... But my problem is related to second part. this first function is correctly working... I have a problem when it is about using the array that it returns outside the method:                                                                                                                           ```t=getData()
    console.log(t)//working
    console.log(t[0][0])// not working here```